# In Laravel, can a migration file create more than one table?

Tags: migration, laravel, laravel-4

I need to create a relevant amount of tables and checking the [Laravel 4 documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/schema) I see the following code:

```
Schema::create('users', function($table)
{
    $table->increments('id');
});
```

I assume that in one migration file, I can create as many tables as I want using the code above. Is this assumption right? Is it a bad practice?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, migrations can do multiple DB modifications (add tables, drop tables, add indexes, etc).

It is not considered bad form. A migration is a collection of steps necessary to upgrade/downgrade your database to the next/previous format, respectively

```php
Schema::create('users', function($table)
{
    $table->increments('id');
});

Schema::create('rights', function($table)
{
    $table->increments('id');
});
```

In our case, migrations are tied to our ticket system. When a feature or bug is to be deployed, the appropriate migration is deployed with it. Sometimes we add columns, new tables, or drop stuff.